# while going through a code I saw a:b in independent variables of a liner regression code. What does it mean?

Tags: r

I am doing a regression analysis and here In the reference code I saw A:B in independent variables of the regression equation. I dont know what it is

Comment: It just indicates an interaction between those variables. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19271/different-ways-to-write-interaction-terms-in-lm

Comment: Study `help("formula")`.